# Conformal mapping proposition proof question

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f:U\to V$ is holomorphic and injective, then $f'(z)\neq 0$ for all
> $z\in U$. In particular, the inverse of $f$ defined on its range is
> holomorphic, and thus the inverse of a conformal map is also
> holomorphic.

This is from Stein's Complex Analysis, and this is the first part of the proof.

Assume by contradiction that $f'(z_0)=0$ for some $z_0\in U$. Then using taylor expansion, we have
$f(z)-f(z_0)=a(z-z_0)^k+G(z)$ for all $z$ near z_0.
Then to use Rouche's theorem, Stein sets $F(z)=a(z-z_0)^k-w$ and says that $f(z)-f(z_0)-w=F(z)+G(z)$. Then he says that we have $|G(z)|<|F(z)|$ and so by Rouche's theorem, $f(z)-f(z_0)-w$ has at least two zeros. Since $f'(z)\neq 0 $ for all $z\neq z_0$ but sufficiently close to $z_0$ it follows that the roots of $f(z)-f(z_0)-w$ are distinct, hence $f$ is not injective, a contradiction.

My main question is, why is $|G(z)|<|F(z)|$?

Comment: Is $w$ an arbitrary element? Can you tell me the Proposition number?

Comment: It's proposition 1.1 on chapter 8!

Comment: It says "sufficiently small $w$"